# Passing a value from a service to a component (Angular2)

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a service:

```
@Inject()    
export class MyService{
...
    // this.status has a value which I can print in the console.
    //Now let's write a function to call it from my component

getGood(): any{
        return this.status;
    }
}
```

Now, in my component:

```
export class MyComponent {

    statusFromServer: number;

    constructor(private router: Router, @Inject(UploadedFile) private _uploadedFile: UploadedFile){
    }    
    .....    
    handleUpload(): void {

        this.statusFromServer = this._uploadedFile.getGood();
        console.log(this.statusFromServer);   
    }         
}
```

What should I do to get this.status can be accessed and printed in the component? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```ts
@Inject()    
export class MyService{
```

should be

```ts
@Injectable()    
export class MyService{
```

```ts
constructor(private router: Router, @Inject(UploadedFile) private _uploadedFile: UploadedFile){
```

should be

```ts
constructor(private router: Router, private _uploadedFile: UploadedFile){
```

If this doesn't help I assume that `MyService.status` is set by some async call and not yet available when `this.statusFromServer = this._uploadedFile.getGood();` is executed.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for String!
Error: No provider for String!
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor]

Comment: But that's not caused by the code in your question. I already explained in the previous question that you can't inject instances of classes that have parameters of type `string` (or `boolean`, `number`, `Object`). For these you actually need `@Inject('somename')` and matching providers.

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
get handleUpload(): void {
   return this._uploadedFile.getGood();  
}
```

Hope this helps!!